# Set Image.Source from photo in camera roll

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, camera-roll

In my Windows Phone 8.1 App i take a photo with the camera and save this in the camera roll and save the image path in a temporary object:

```
var picture = library.SavePictureToCameraRoll(fileName, e.ImageStream);
geophoto.ImagePath = picture.GetPath();
```

In another page of my app i want to load this photo from the camera roll and set the saved path as the source of an Image object:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(App.Current.Geophoto.ImagePath, UriKind.Absolute);
ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
this.ShutterImage.Source = imgSource;
```

The saved path of the image is e.g. `"file:///C:/Data/Users/Public/Pictures/Camera Roll/201506191442443805.jpg"`

In runtime the image goes blank when i try to set a new source. Is there  something wrong with the path or with the code?

Comment: You don't need to use a `Uri` object. Just use `Image.Source = "file:///C:/Data/Users/Public/Pictures/Camera Roll/201506191442443805.jpg"` or preferably data bind that string to the `Image.Source` property in XAML.

Comment: Why not store the `Picture` in a Geophoto property, and restore the image from its `GetImage` method?

Comment: @Sheridan When i use your code the following error occurs: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'.

Comment: @Clemens It is also possible that the user makes 100 photos and i dont want to save the bitmaps as objects but only as referencing URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that i have no direct access to camera roll through the path. So i solved my problem with the following code:

```
    private BitmapImage GetThumbnailFromCameraRoll(string path)
    {
        MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
        var pictures = mediaLibrary.Pictures;
        foreach (var picture in pictures)
        {
            var camerarollPath = picture.GetPath();
            if (camerarollPath == path)
            {
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(picture.GetThumbnail());
                return image;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```